# Как вывести трехмерный массив в c#? и как его заполнить?

Tags: c#, массивы

Допустим обычный массив можно задать так
`int[] array = new int[] { 1 , 2 , 3 };`
А двухмерный так `int[,] array1 = { { 1 , 2 , 3 }, { 4 , 5 , 6} };`
но как вывести трехмерный массив и как его наполнить числами
я не могу просто понять написали мы так `int [,,] array2 = new int[2 , 3 , 4];`???
я не могу просто понять эти числа которые вводим в [2,3,4] как их допустим задать так {1 ,2 ,3}?

Comment: [2,3,4] это размер массива. При чем тут {1,2,3}?

Comment: я это к примеру,я имел виду в одномерных и двухмерных мы задаем через скобки, а как также задать с помощью трёхмерного?

Comment: Точно так же. Только скобок больше. Например  {{{},{}},{{},{}}}

Comment: Я так понял что это тоже самое что и двухмерный и одномерный только мы пишем int[,,] arr = new int[2,3,4] { { {1,2,3}, {2,3,4 } }, { {1,2,3},{1,3,2},{1,2,3} }, { {2,2,2}, {1,1,1}, {1,2,3},{1,2,3} }  }

Comment: я изменил комент

Comment: Нет, совсем не так.

Comment: можеш навести пример?  залей на codepen если да

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно и так(https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays)   :

int[, ,] array1 = new int[4, 2, 3];

От многомерных массивов надо отличать массив массивов или так называемый "зубчатый массив":

```
int[][] nums = new int[3][];
nums[0] = new int[2] { 1, 2 };          // выделяем память для первого подмассива
nums[1] = new int[3] { 1, 2, 3 };       // выделяем память для второго подмассива
nums[2] = new int[5] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; // выделяем память для третьего подмассива
```

Или так:

```
int[][,] nums = new int[3][,] 
{
    new int[,] { {1,2}, {3,4} },
    new int[,] { {1,2}, {3,6} },
    new int[,] { {1,2}, {3,5}, {8, 13} } 
};
```

Так здесь у нас массив из трех массивов, причем каждый из этих массивов представляет двухмерный массив.

Используя вложенные циклы, можно перебирать зубчатые массивы. Например:

```
int[][] numbers = new int[3][];
numbers[0] = new int[] { 1, 2 };
numbers[1] = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
numbers[2] = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
foreach(int[] row in numbers)
{
    foreach(int number in row)
    {
        Console.Write($"{number} \t");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}

// перебор с помощью цикла for
for (int i = 0; i<numbers.Length;i++)
{
    for (int j =0; j<numbers[i].Length; j++)
    {
        Console.Write($"{numbers[i][j]} \t");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: мозг кипит уже 2 час от массивов никогда не понимал трехмерные массивы, да и это из metanit взято где я учу c#

Comment: А что тут сложного?Сначала было число,потом число объединилось с другими числами в массив,потом массив объединился в массив 2 уровня с другим массивом и и тогда народ огня развязал войну(то есть я хотел сказать и тд)

Comment: да не могу понять что означают цифры [4,2,3] если в одномерном это как [4] {1,2,3,4}. В двумерном [2] { {1,2,3}, {1,2,3} } а в трёх мерном как это вывести вот так я не могу понять

Comment: [4,3,3] { {{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3}},  {{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3}}, {{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3}}, {{1,2,3},{1,2,3},{1,2,3}}}

Comment: я так понял это можно приставить ввиде таблици - https://imgur.com/a/gAwgppg (вроде там понятно написал:D )

Comment: таблица двумерный массив,а куб трехмерный массив,а следующий измерениях почитайте литературу сами либо в универе расскажут))

Comment: ну это типо вроде куба можно приставить? и также само со всех сторон? как на фото